# removeRow in QTableView/QAbstractTableModel by CheckBox

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt5, qtableview, qabstracttablemodel

I've created a table view where I'm trying to drop rows by clicking the checkbox embedded in the table view. I get to the point where it indexes the correct row when the checkbox is deselected, but the model refuse to remove the row and instead returns 'False'. Any thoughts? Still new to tableviews after switching from tablewidgets

```
class pandasModel(QAbstractTableModel):
    def __init__(self, data, check_col=[0, 0]):
        QAbstractTableModel.__init__(self)
        self._data = data
        self._check = check_col

        cs = 0
        if check_col[1]: cs = 2
        self._checked = [[cs for i in range(self.columnCount())] for j in range(self.rowCount())]

    def rowCount(self, parent=QModelIndex):
        return self._data.shape[0]

    def columnCount(self, parent=QModelIndex):
        return self._data.shape[1]



    def data(self, index, role):

        if index.isValid():
            data = self._data.iloc[index.row(), index.column()]

            if role == Qt.DisplayRole:
                if isinstance(data, float):
                    return f'{data:,.2f}'
                elif isinstance(data, (int, np.int64)):
                    return f'{data:,}'
                else:
                    return str(data)
            elif role == Qt.TextAlignmentRole:
                if isinstance(data, (float, int, np.int64)):
                    return Qt.AlignVCenter + Qt.AlignRight
            elif role == Qt.CheckStateRole:
                if self._check[0] > 0:
                    if self._check[0] == index.column():
                        return self._checked[index.row()][index.column()]

        return None

    def flags(self, index):
        if not index.isValid(): return
        return Qt.ItemIsSelectable | Qt.ItemIsEnabled | Qt.ItemIsUserCheckable | Qt.ItemIsEditable

    def setData(self, index, value, role):
        if not index.isValid() or role != Qt.CheckStateRole: return False
        self._checked[index.row()][index.column()] = value
        if value == 0:
            print('checked')
            self.removeRow(index.row()) #THIS IS WHERE IT RETURNS FALSE
        self.dataChanged.emit(index, index)
        return True

    def headerData(self, col, orientation, role):
        if orientation == Qt.Horizontal and role == Qt.DisplayRole:
            return self._data.columns[col]

        return None
```

Comment: From the [docs](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qabstracttablemodel.html#subclassing): You need to call `beginRemoveRows()`, then `removeRow()` and finally `endRemoveRows()`

Comment: provide a [mre]